# CollectionViewFlowLayout's collectionViewContentSize() in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionviewlayout

I cannot retrieve contentSize from flow layout with the following code

```
let contentSize: CGSize = self.collectionView?.collectionViewLayout.collectionViewContentSize()!
```

Instead I get error:

> Could not find member 'collectionViewContentSize'

If I print value it returns properly:

```
println("content size \(self.collectionView?.collectionViewLayout.collectionViewContentSize())")
```

Is this swift compiler issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You **must** cast `collectionViewLayout` to specific layout. If you use `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` it will look something like this:

```
if let flow = collectionMain.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout
{
    let contentSize: CGSize = flow.collectionViewContentSize()
}
```

Comment: But collectionViewContentSize() is a method declared on UICollectionViewLayout.

Comment: Yeah, that's what was bugging me. Anyway that solved my problem. Thanks!

Comment: I'm not pretty sure why that is the case. I think it has something related with `collectionViewContentSize ` being declared in category/extension, instead of the class itself.